# Not able to overwrite object properties in "create" method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, custom-validators

I have a simple table for storing users accounts information (emails and passwords) with two additional columns:

1. is_active - says if user account is enable or disabled - the column
   type is *boolean* and in the context of DB2 it is mapped with
   *decimal(1)*
2. registration_date - says when the user  was created - the column
   type is *datetime* and in the context ofDB2 it is mapped with
   *datetime*

As this fields will not be set by the user, I have deleted their inputs from the users _form.

I want to populated this fields in my users controller as follows:

```
def create

   @security_user = SecurityUser.new(params[:security_user])

   @security_user.is_active = 0
   @security_user.registration_date = DateTime.now

  ...

end
```

But I can not pass the validations that I have in the model. They looks like:

```
class SecurityUser < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Loading custom validators
  require 'lib/date_format_validator'
  ...

  # Accessible columns
  ...

  # Relationships
  ...

  # Validations
  validates :is_active, inclusion: { in: 0..1, message: "only '0' and '1' allowed"}, presence: true
  validates :registration_date, date_format:true , presence: true

end
```

where the 'lib/date_format_validator' looks like follows:

```
class DateFormatValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator

  def validate_each(object, attribute, value)
    if (DateTime.parse(value) rescue ArgumentError) == ArgumentError
      object.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is not valid datetime")
    end
  end

end
```

What I am doing wrong?

EDIT: The screenshot below displays the errors:

[image]

EDIT2: Sam Ruby's answer helps me to finish with something like this for my custom validator method:

```
class DateFormatValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator

  def validate_each(object, attribute, value)
    unless value.kind_of? DateTime || (DateTime.parse(value) rescue ArgumentError) != ArgumentError
      object.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is not valid datetime")
    end
  end

end
```

and to transform the validates method for the is_active column as follows:

```
validates :is_active, inclusion: { in: [ true, false ], message: "only 'true' and 'false' allowed"}
```

because as it is said in the official documentation:

```
Since false.blank? is true, if you want to validate the presence of a boolean field you should use validates :field_name, :inclusion => { :in => [true, false] }.
```

Comment: What's the actual error message? I see in the controller that you're manually setting the `is_active` and `registration_date` fields, so I'm guessing it's not the `presence` portion of the validation that's failing?

Comment: I have a feeling that having a 0 value, even with that inclusion validation, is going to result it a falsey value and therefore be invalid. Can I suggest 't' and 'f'?

Comment: @FluffyJack The field type is decimal(1). Do you offer to change the type of the field and to store "T" and "F" instead "0" and "1". Also, as it is boolean type in the context of rails, it is displayed as checkbox with value "0" and "1" in the form.

Comment: @normalocity Yes, the other validations fails, that's why I suppose I have done something wrong with the validations definitions.

Comment: Hang on... why are you doing validation for the presence of a boolean anyway? Default it to one or the other. If it's being set in the form, then the form helper will take care of everything really.

Comment: 0 is a falsey value, if you try to validate it, it will fail. Instead, get rid of the validation, and set it as the default in the model instead of the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to validate the ActiveRecord object as if the columns are of type String.  But since you have defined your columns as boolean and datetime, what you will be validating will be of type TrueClass, FalseClass or ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone.

In other words, the values are already parsed.

`true` is never `0` or `1`.

`DateTime.parse(DateTime.now)` will always raise `ArgumentError`

If you want to validate the unparsed values, do so in the controller.

Comment: Thanks, I have some difficulties but your answer helps me to solve my issue.